# Why does my <td> have so much space to the right?

Tags: html, dreamweaver

I am trying to have an icon image sit left of a contact phone number and I have the image and text in separate  next to each other. The image is showing extra space to the right of it and I don't know how to fix it. I've tried specifying width and padding, but neither seem to work.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIKmK.png)

```
<td colspan="5" style="padding-top: 10px; font-size: 22px; letter-spacing: 2px; font-family:montserrat;">BEN CHADWICK</td>
```

Director, ECL Energy
  
    
     
    0438 634 206
  
  
    **www.eclenergy.com.au**

Comment: Can you share the code on CodeSandbox?

Comment: did you try to remove the second td and writed down them in one / or leave second td empty and write the number after image tag ?

Comment: Hi @MetByrdy, thanks for the reply. I've tried that, but the text doesn't sit how I'd like next to the image. I want the text to float center of the image, but instead it aligns to the bottom of the image.

Comment: Than you can give style to your text actually wrapping as it <span class="centeralize"> by using position attribute make it absolute ?

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't doing anything either.

Answer (score 1):

Can you get the result you want without using a table divider  between the icon and the phone number? For example:

```html
<td> <img src="https://i.ibb.co/PzpsRtW/PHONE-email-signature.png" alt="phone number" width="28"> 0438 634 206</td>
```

Comment: Hey Dan, thanks for the reply. I have tried that, but the text doesn't align how I would like next to the icon image. It sits bottom flush and I'd like it to float center next to the text if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the image and the phone number in the same th tag.

like,

```html
<td><img src="https://i.ibb.co/PzpsRtW/PHONE-email-signature.png" width="20px" height="20px"> 0438 634 206</td>
```

In case you want border to right of the image you can use

`border-right: /*desired border*/;`

in your css.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this inline to your  element:

```
<td style="text-align:center;">
```

Or you can edit your css file (if you have one):

```
td {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Hey @stafino, thanks for the help, but that only centers the <td> within the whole table. I'm trying to get the text to essentially lift up a bit so it's center to the image next to it.